# Difference between $http.get and method:'GET'

Tags: mysql, angularjs, http, httprequest, crud

I'm using Spring Data REST and have a MySQL DB to manage my data.
With AngularJS I programmed my first page and want to get data from my DB.

To get my data I know about two different ways:

```
$http.get('http://myURL')
```

and

```
$http({
    method:'GET'
    url:'http://myURL'
}
```

But where's the difference between them?

Thanks for help!

Comment: `$http.get` is a shortcut to `$http({})`. exactly like `$http.post`, `$http.put`, `$http.delete`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no difference, `$http.get('http://myURL')` is just a shortcut for `$http({method:'GET, url:'http://myURL'}`

Answer (score 1):

1. First way of getting the response is the short form of the second one.
2. If you want to set some headers for the request you have to write the request via second way... that is much more clear way of writing it.

   ```
   var req = { method: 'POST', url: 'http://example.com', headers: {       'Content-Type': undefined },  data: { test: 'test' }} $http(req).then(function(){...}, function(){...});
   ```

Answer (score -1):

**$http.get('url')** is just the shorthand notation of writing **$http({method:'GET ',url:'url '})**

Its same as **jQuery** is the shorthand notation for **JavaScript**

If you want to  modify header in the api call,use second notation