# What's the difference between $http.get and $.ajax with type 'GET'?

Tags: angularjs, http, get

I understand that there is a [post about this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37859585/difference-between-http-get-and-methodget).

But from my observation, these 2 methods produce different results.

If I am using this:

```
$.ajax({
          url: myDataURL,
          type: 'GET'
      });
```

it returns results.

However, if i write in this way:

```
$http.get(myDataURL)
```

it throws the error:

```
Invalid CORS request
```

Did I miss something?

**P.S.:**

My data URL is from Jetty Geoserver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CORS` means **Cross-origin resource sharing**. You have to to configure the webserver where you are sending your `$http.get` request to allow cross-domain requests. You will see in the HTTP header `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`.

If your destination server supports CORS, you will get this response:

`Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`

Comment: Thanks for your post. but the thing is, if i get this error through $http.get, but there is no error when using $.ajax? I thought both of them are essentially the same?

Comment: Just want to say, this is possibly caused by prefilter in angularjs which has been customized by my colleague without my knowledge. But yes, your post does lead me to find out more, so i accept this.

Comment: Glad I could help @zflaw !

Answer (score 0):

You will need to set headers:

```
var req = { method: 'POST', 
            url: 'http://example.com', 
            headers: {'Content-Type': undefined },  
            data: { test: 'test' }
          }
```

Comment: I am writing this: 
$http.get(myDataURL, { headers: { 'Content-Type': undefined } });

but it still throws the error.